# How to read a file AS hex in c (any file not just a binary) to obtain the File's signature with restrictions

Tags: c, file-io

I'm completely stumped for this assignment. As the title says I'm trying to obtain the file's hexadecimal file signature in order to determine what type of file it is. I've tried many different things, my code right now looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    FILE* fp;
    char* buffer;

    fp = fopen("Test.class", "rb");  //I'm just using Test.class for testing the program. Test.class is a java class file
    fread(buffer, 10, 10, fp);
    printf("%x", buffer);
}
```

I'm also restricted to only using the following library functions:
fopen
fscanf
fclose
fread
printf

I was expecting to get the same output(the file signature or at least part of it) (The file signature for a java class file is CA FE BA BE) every time I ran the program but I keep getting different random hex values. Here are a few:

```
9e53a710
a8290890
ceb1beb0
```

I thought that maybe I shouldn't use a char* buffer because maybe the program is reading the values as chars so I tried using a void* pointer instead and got similar results of more random hex values with the same length. I've also tired for looping through each bite and I've other things like using fscanf to no avail. I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I've been trying to debug this for days.

Comment: have you tried `fscanf` for taking input in hexadecimal format

Comment: `unsigned v; fread(&v, sizeof(v), 1, fp); printf("%x", v);`

Comment: Or `unsigned char buff[4];
 fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), fp);
 for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buff); ++i)
  printf("%02X", buff[i]);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I changed the code to 'code' FILE* fp; fp = fopen("Test.class", "rb"); unsgined char buff[4]; fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), fp); int i; for(i = 0; i < sizeof(buff); ++i) printf("%02x", buff[i]); but its still printing random hex values each time. I also tried changing the code to the first suggestion that you poseted and that one seems to get a bit closer to what I want. It prints four hex characters starting with 7ff but that last character is random and this still looks nothing like the file signature that I was expecting.

Comment: I don't reproduce it. Have you rebuilt the program? Also check if the file was opened successfully.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes 'code'FILE* fp;
        fp = fopen("Test.class", "rb");
        unsigned v;
        fread(&v, sizeof(v), 1, fp);
        printf("%x", v);

Comment: Check return value of `fopen` and `fread`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Actually here is a pastebin link that should make it easier to debug: [link]https://pastebin.com/bzyuCBqy I compiled using gcc file_name.c -o reader and excuted with ./reader

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm not sure how to check the return value. How should I print the result of fopen and fread they are not strings so what should I print them as?

Comment: such as `fp = fopen(...); if(fp == NULL){ perror("fopen"); return -1;}`

Comment: `if(sizeof(buff) != fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), fp)){ perror("fread"); return -1;}`

Comment: `if(1 != fread(&v, sizeof(v), 1, fp)){ perror("fread"); return -1;}`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY fp is not NULL and fread is returning 0 [link]https://pastebin.com/7VPYpzsT

Comment: If `fread` returns `0`, reading failed.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY then why is random hex still printed and how can I fix it so it does read? I'm doing this over ssh to my schools's server if that means anything.

Comment: If the file has been successfully opened but failed to read the data, random value will be displayed as uninitialized variables will be displayed.

Comment: I guess, I think the file exists, but its contents are not.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so I tried a recompile of Test.class and now it outputs the file signature but backwards which is strange but at least I know its reading it correctly. Thanks. You saved me big time.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY actually after testing this with a few other file formats the program is only working with reading a java class signature and even then it reads it backwards. I tried reading pdf and png files and got the wrong result both times.[link]https://pastebin.com/nGvHnheL

Comment: Perhaps it is because of endianness that seems to be opposite. Use array of `unsigned char` version.

Comment: The file signature is likely backwards because the SSH server is a [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) machine, where an integer `0xDDCCBBAA` is `AA BB CC DD` in a file. In the case of `CA FE BA BE`, you'll get `0xBEBAFECA`. Using `unsigned char buff[4];` with `fread(buff, 1, sizeof buff, fp);` will prevent this (see [this example on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7AKajjM3); you can also [run a slightly modified version](https://repl.it/Mfkb/1)). In the future, you can verify the number of bytes in a file using, for example, `wc -c Test.class`.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune your example is very helpful except for the fact that I can't use memcmp. I'm only allowed to use fopen(), fread(), fclose(), fscanf(), and printf() in my program. I didn't know about memcmp though so that will be helpful in the future.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I looked up how to make a function that works like memcmp so that's fine but my program still won't read a png's file signature. I added the png signature to your code and the my_memcmp function but it prints unknown signature. I'm also running this code on my home 64 bit machine now I dont know if that changes anything but your java signature code still detected the Test.class file so I dont think anything changed.

Comment: If the buffer is still only 4 bytes, it won't match the 8-byte PNG file signature.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune [link]https://pastebin.com/y8jRBRiu I changed the buffer to a size of 8. The java file still works but the png does not.

Comment: Worked for me on several PNG files, so your program is working fine. Try `hexdump -C -n 8 cat.png` or `od -t x1 -N 8 cat.png`, or modify your program to print the bytes.